# Top 2 positions in every company (based on their CTC)

Tags: pandas

My data set contains company column, job position and ctc column. I want to get top 2 positions in each company based on CTC. Did some group by as below...

I tried -

grp112 = df23.groupby(['company_name','job_position'],as_index=False)['ctc'].max()
df24= pd.merge(df23, grp112, on=['company_hash','job_position'], how='inner',suffixes=(None,'_maxCtc'))

Above 2 lines will show job position based on max ctc, I am not sure how to get 2nd highest paid job position !

Comment: Something like: `df23.sort_values('ctc', ascending=False).groupby('company_name').head(2)` ?

Comment: @JonClements, thanks for answer. Is there a away to get top 2 job_positons based on ctc in above code. I guess we can use job_position along with company_name in groupby but not sure if that would necesssarily return top 2 job_postions !

Comment: Does the above code not produce the output you're after? Could you describe what your expected output is?